# How to get the text-area.width in the preset shape from openxml?

Tags: c#, powerpoint, openxml, ecma

Does anybody know how to get the width of the text area width and position in **powerpoint**?

I get the information of Cx, Cy, Off.X|Y,but the infos are just for the shape,not for the text area in the shape.

And when i strenth the width and the text-area.width change, so maybe it's respect to the outsize-shape.But I am not found the related information from stack overflow or ecma.

[=> Image - Shape.text.area.width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1W7lj.png)

Comment: What shape? What document are you asking about? Word, Excel, Visio?

Answer (score 0):

## Doc

- [ECMA-376](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm)

## How

- please download the release version of **part1**, for example: **ECMA-376 4th edition Part 1**
- unzip **ECMA-376, Fourth Edition, Part 1 - Fundamentals And Markup Language Reference.zip**/ **OfficeOpenXML-DrawingMLGeometries.zip** to find **presetShapeDefinitions.xml**
- every shape is defined, and the `<rect>` is the definition for placeing the text in the shape dynamically

Comment: This isn't an answer. "Read the docs" should be a comment. Besides, I'd check Microsoft's SDK, not ECMAs specifications for questions on Office Open XML

Comment: Actually, this is the correct answer. There is no other answer. If you don't know Openxml, don't comment.